# I want to call CallBack function of javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, invokescript

when I insert address, the program will return GPS value.

**code:**

```
var callback = new function func1(status, result) {

    if (status === daum.maps.services.Status.OK) {

           var coords = new daum.maps.LatLng(result.addr[0].lat, result.addr[0].lng);

           var marker = new daum.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: coords
           });
           var infowindow = new daum.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<div style="width:150px;text-align:center;padding:6px 0;">우리회사</div>'
           });
           infowindow.open(map, marker);

           map.setCenter(coords);
    }
}
geocoder.addr2coord(loc, callback);
```

**And C#:**

```
 try
        {
            string url = "D:/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication6/WindowsFormsApplication6\\DaumMapAPI.html";
            webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("geocoder.addr2coord", new object[] { "강원도 원주시 학성길 121", ??? });
            webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I don't know what '???' will be inserted.

Please, Help me!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Javascript it seems to me that the

```
geocoder.addr2coord(loc, callback);
```

Is called immediately upon loading of the page. I think what you want is another wrapper function that you can then call from C# like so (notice the new `search()` function:

```
var callback = new function func1(status, result) {
    if (status === daum.maps.services.Status.OK) {

       var coords = new daum.maps.LatLng(result.addr[0].lat, result.addr[0].lng);

       var marker = new daum.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: coords
       });
       var infowindow = new daum.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<div style="width:150px;text-align:center;padding:6px 0;">우리회사</div>'
       });
       infowindow.open(map, marker);

       map.setCenter(coords);
    }
}
function search(loc) {
    geocoder.addr2coord(loc, callback);
}
```

Then in C# you can do what you did, but with the new `search` function instead.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But my program still return NullReferenceException...

Comment: Ah I was under the impression that the error was in javascript, but you're saying that the error is in C#? Are you sure the 'webBrowser1' variable is properly instantiated?

Comment: Thanks for your fast comment, I don't know whether the webbrowser1 variable is instantiated or not.

Comment: webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("search", new object[] { "강원도 원주시 학성길 121" });
here's a new code.

Comment: can you check whether webBrowser1 == null or perhaps webBrowser1.Document == null? If this is the case, your problem has nothing to do with Javascript

Comment: OK, I solved it, I didn't know that webBrowser==null. So, I move 'webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("search", new object[] { loc });' sentence to last sentence. And it works!

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I could be of some help